# Error querying Active Directory via SQL Server provider using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using `OPENROWSET` to query information from Active Directory using the `ADsDSOObject` OleDB provider.

When running as a non-SysAdmin account I get the following error.

> Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'ADSDSOObject' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

I am using `OPENROWSET` that does not require a linked server setup as below...

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject', 'adsdatasource;Domain\Username;Password',
                'SELECT sAMAccountName, department, division, manager, employeeID, displayName, givenname, mail, sn, title, sAMAccountType, streetAddress, l, st, postalCode, telephoneNumber, whenChanged, accountExpires, badPwdCount, lastLogon, pwdLastSet, userAccountControl 
                 FROM ''LDAP://DOMAIN/OU=locations,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com'' WHERE objectClass =  ''User'' and userAccountControl = 512 and sAMAccountType = 805306368'
```

What rights am I missing to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a small bug with SQL Server and not a rights issue.  To allow this you must disable the "Disallow adhoc access" parameter for the ADsDSOObject Linked Server Provider but it is tricky.

Launch SSMS and go to your Linked Server providers.  Expand the properties for the ADsDSOObject provider.

[image: ADsDSOObject Provider Properties]

The next step is counter intuitive.  Check the box next to "Disallow adhoc access" and click OK.  You actually want to set this to false but there is a trick to this.

[image: Disallow adhoc access]

This creates the appropriate entry in your registry.  It did not exist before.  Launch RegEdit and find the registry key that coincides with checkbox you just checked.  It will be in a different location depending on which version of SQL Server you are using.  Mine was in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\Providers\ADSDSOObject but yours will most likely be slightly different.

[image: DisallowAdHocAccess Registry Setting]

At this point you want to change that 1 to a 0.  You will also need to restart the SQL Server service.  Once that is complete you should be able to use OPENROWSET for that 1 specific provider.

Comment: Nailed it!  Works great.